# The run destination My Mac is not valid for Running the scheme 'My-iOS-App'

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I'm trying to do an `xcodebuild` and archive my app from the command line. However, for some reason `My Mac` shows up as a valid run scheme for my iOS app. And that's why running this will throw.

```
xcodebuild: error: Failed to build workspace MyApp with scheme 'My-iOS-App.
Reason: The run destination My Mac is not valid for Running the scheme ''My-iOS-App'.
```

Any ideas as to how I can fix this?

Answer (score 23):

Make sure none of your targets (including tests) have `SUPPORTS_MACCATALYST` property set to `YES`. 
If any of the targets have this property, `My Mac` destination will show up.

Comment: Thank you. My test targets set SUPPORTS_MACCATALYST to YES, so I deleted the two test targets, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not really on topic because I'm not building for iOS, but I found this searching for that error. In my case, it was a missing SDK version referenced in the build settings (an old open source project I downloaded). Changing that to the (only one available) macOS 10.11 solved the issue. (macOS 10.11 and Xcode 7.3.1 here). Sorry if not an appropriate answer.

Comment: Hi! Your answer is clear, thank you. For further answers focus on the subject and the answer itself.